# backuppc : client host running windows 7 and Mac OSX

Tags: macosx, backuppc

I would like to setup Backuppc to Backup files when the remote hosts are running windows 7 or Mac OSX.
Thunk's for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can find kind of good tutorial here:

http://lifeofageekadmin.com/installing-backuppc/

It covers Windows and OSX.